Extraction Pre-Post correlation of repeated measures design
According to various references, such as https://matthewbjane.github.io/blog-posts/blog-post-3.html  the correlation between The pretest and posttest scores (paired t-test) can be calculated if the value of paired t-statistic (t) is available.
Calculate pre/post correlation
r <- (t^2*(SD_pre^2 + SD_post^2) - N * M_change^2) / (2t^2SD_pre*SD_post)
My question is, when we need to apply a nonparametric test (Wilcoxon signed-rank test) instead of a parametric one (paired t-test), how can we calculate the correlation?

Could you elaborate a little on this question?  How one "calculates" anything doesn't depend on an (unrelated) test.  Are you wondering, for instance, whether there is some kind of "correlation" that naturally corresponds to the Wilcoxon signed-rank test in the way a Pearson correlation might be associated with a paired t test?  Are you trying to ask whether Pearson correlation coefficients are appropriate or useful in conjunction with rank-based tests?  Maybe you're trying to ask something else?

@whuber, thank you so much for the comment. According to the reference and formula mentioned above, if we have information about the standard deviation of pre-scores and post-scores, the number of observations, the difference between the mean of pre-scores and post-scores, and the t-statistic (after applying a paired t-test), we can calculate the correlation between pre-scores and post-scores. Now my question is, what would be the formula when we run the Wilcoxon signed-rank test (where ( W ) is the output of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test) and we no longer have access to the t-statistic?

@whuber, It seems that the formula can be used when the distribution of the mean difference follows normality. But how about when we need to use a nonparametric one? How can we extract the value of correlation when we have access to the value of ( W ) and not the t-statistic?

The formula is pure algebra--it has nothing to do with any distributional assumptions--and the correlation coefficient is Pearson's.  You cannot recover a Pearson correlation coefficient from any test based only on ranks. With some rank-based tests you can analogously compute the Spearman correlation, but the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is not one of them (since it doesn't involve the ranks of the two samples separately).

@whuber, thank you for the advice. I am working on a meta-analysis study. In this study, there are 10 publications that used the Wilcoxon signed-rank test for paired data. In order to use the meta-analysis (mean difference), I need to have access to the value of correlation. So, for those publications where the Wilcoxon signed-rank test has been used, the correlation cannot be calculated. Am I right?

Because the Wilcoxon test doesn't evaluate the mean difference, it's hard to see where you're going with this.
